# CSS variables inheritance and nested shadow roots

Tags: css, vue.js, css-variables, shadow-root

I am using VueJS to define two custom web elements, `service-card` and `slot-card`.
I allow CSS variables, e.g. `--pm-scale: 0.75`,  to customize the style of the elements.

`slot-card` can be used independently, but it is also part of the inner HTML of `service-card`:

```
<slot-card ...>
<service-card ...>
    ...
    <slot-card ...>
```

In both elements I have the following css, "injected into the shadow root" according to the VueJS documentation

```
:host {
    --pm-scale: 1;
}
```

*("An SFC loaded in custom element mode inlines its  tags as strings of CSS and exposes them under the component's styles option. This will be picked up by defineCustomElement and injected into the element's shadow root when instantiated.")*

My problem is that in the page below, the pm-scale value of .75 correctly overrides the variable for the top-level `service-card`, but the inner `slot-card` reverts to the default value of 1:

```
<style>
.pm-widget {
            --pm-scale: .75;
</style>
<body>
<service-card class="pm-widget" ...>
    ...
    <slot-card class="pm-widget" ...>
</body>
```

In Chrome devtools I see both the `:host` and `pm-widget` styles applied to both elements; for `service-card`, `pm-widget` values overrides `:host` values, however for `slot-card` the opposite happens... so it looks like the `:host` selector on the inner `slot-card` is considered more specific than the `pm-widget` class?
A top-level `slot-card` element is correctly styled with the `pm-widget` variable values.

What is the best way to fix this?
Thanks!

I tried to override CSS variables used in the nested web component's styles. I expect values defined in the final document to override values defined in the inlined :host selector of the nested component.

Answer (score 0):

Using an internal variable seems to work, although I don't fully understand why:

```
:host {
    --pm-scale-internal: var(--pm-scale, 1);
}
```

Comment: Because it inherits, so make it ``--pm-scale: var(--pm-scale, 1)``